# Masking a NetCDF file 2D lat/lon with a shapefile in Python

Tags: python, rasterio, rioxarray

I am trying to mask a NetCDF file with an shapefile.
Here is my shapefile:

```
Africa_Shape = geopandas.read_file('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/HighresMIP/control_1950/iho/iho.shp', crs="epsg:4326")
```

And here is my NetCDF file (MSWEP_monthly) structure and the procedure that I am following to clip the original dataset
[image]

And my results are all the values nan.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/202

Simplest method:

```py
min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = Africa_Shape.total_bounds
xds_clipped  = xds.where((xds.lon<=max_x) & (xds.lon>=min_x) & (xds.lat<=max_y) & (xds.lat>=min_y), drop=True)
```

But, I would recommend looking into `xoak`